# tikz package not working with university thesis class, AIT

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am using `ait-thesis` template, It gives error when I wrap a `tikz picture` inside a `figure`. I tried to add remove package and found that `\usepackage{tikz}` is in conflict with `aitthesis.cls` here is the link to [class](https://github.com/aitcsim/ait-thesis-latex-template/blob/master/aitthesis.cls). If I place tikz package before it then problem does not arises but remaining document is all messed up. Real error is `too many }s, Latex Error: \begin{document} end with \end{figure}`. The error file says: `\color@endbox ->\color@endgroup \egroup`. Can you please solve it. 
My code works in standalone document class. Working Example without `aitthesis class`

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tikz}

 \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{figure}
\centering
\tikzset{%
neuron missing/.style={
draw=none, 
scale=4,
text height=0.333cm,
execute at begin node=\color{black}$\vdots$
},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.5cm, y=1.5cm, >=stealth]

\foreach \m/\l [count=\y] in {1,2,3}
{
\node [circle,fill=green!50,minimum size=1cm] (input-\m) at (0,2.5-\y) {};
}
\foreach \m/\l [count=\y] in {4}
{
 \node [circle,fill=green!50,minimum size=1cm ] (input-\m) at (0,-2.5) {};
}

\node [neuron missing]  at (0,-1.5) {};


\foreach \m [count=\y] in {1}
\node [circle,fill=red!50,minimum size=1cm ] (hidden-\m) at (2,0.75) {};

\foreach \m [count=\y] in {2}
\node [circle,fill=red!50,minimum size=1cm ] (hidden-\m) at (2,-1.85) {};

\node [neuron missing]  at (2,-0.3) {};


\foreach \m [count=\y] in {1}
 \node [circle,fill=blue!50,minimum size=1cm ] (output-\m) at (4,1.5-\y) {};

\foreach \m [count=\y] in {2}
 \node [circle,fill=blue!50,minimum size=1cm ] (output-\m) at (4,-0.5-\y) {};

\node [neuron missing]  at (4,-0.4) {};

\foreach \l [count=\i] in {1,2,3,256}
 \draw [<-] (input-\i) -- ++(-1,0)
 node [above, midway] {$I_{\l}$};

\foreach \l [count=\i] in {1,16}
\node [above] at (hidden-\i.north) {$H_{\l}$};

\foreach \l [count=\i] in {1,16}
\draw [->] (output-\i) -- ++(1,0)
node [above, midway] {$O_{ \l}$};

\foreach \i in {1,...,4}
\foreach \j in {1,...,2}
\draw [->] (input-\i) -- (hidden-\j);

\foreach \i in {1,...,2}
\foreach \j in {1,...,2}
\draw [->] (hidden-\i) -- (output-\j);

 %\foreach \l [count=\x from 0] in {Input, Hidden, Ouput}
 % \node [align=center, above] at (\x*2,2) {\l \\ layer};

\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119587/171268` answer solved the issue don't know if it is correct way though.

Comment: You can always use standalone class for the tikzpictures and \includegraphics the results (assuming no conflict with graphicx).

Comment: You can put the tikzpicture into a savebox.  The figure will use the box immediately, even if it doesn't print until later.

Answer (score 1):

as you find yourself, problem is in document class `aitthesis`. you have two options:

- consider [JLDiaz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/12571/jldiaz) answer on question (to which your question is duplicate)
- check if the following solution works for you:

  ```
  \documentclass{report}
  \usepackage{capt-of}    % new
  \usepackage{tikz}

  \begin{document}
      \begin{center}
  \tikzset{
  neuron missing/.style = {scale=4, text depth=1.5ex, inner sep=0pt,
                           execute at begin node=$\vdots$
                          },
            circ/.style = {circle, fill=#1, minimum size = 1cm},
  every label/.append style = {label distance = 0pt, inner sep=2pt, font=\small}
          }

  \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.6cm, y=1.6cm, >=stealth]

  \foreach \m/\n in {1/1,2,3,4,5/256}
  {
  \ifnum\m=4
      \node [neuron missing] (input-\m) at (0,2.5-\m) {};
  \else
      \node [circ=green!50]  (input-\m) at (0,2.5-\m) {};
      \draw [<-] (input-\m.west) -- node [above] {$I_{\n}$} + (-1,0);
  \fi
  }
  \foreach \m/\n in {1,2,3,4/16}
  {
  \ifnum\m=3
      \node [neuron missing]  (hiden-\m)  at (2,2-\m) {};
      \node [neuron missing]  (output-\m) at (4,2-\m) {};
  \else
      \node [circ=red!50,
             label=$H_{\n}$]  (hiden-\m)  at (2,2-\m) {};
      \node [circ=blue!50]    (output-\m) at (4,2-\m) {};
      \draw [->] (output-\m.east) -- node [above] {$O_{\n}$} + (1,0);
  \fi
  }
  \foreach \m in {1,2,3,5}
  \foreach \n in {1,2,4}
  {
  \draw [->]  (input-\m) -- (hiden-\n);
  }
  \foreach \m in {1,2,4}
  \foreach \n in {1,2,4}
  {
  \draw [->]  (hiden-\m) edge (output-\n);
  }
  \end{tikzpicture}
      \captionof{figure}{Caption}
  \label{fig:my_label}
      \end{center}
  \end{document}
  ```

as you can see, image is `center` environment, i.e. it not float anymore. with this (i hope so) the malfunction of `aitthesis` document class will be avoided.

i also took liberty and rewrote your image code that it is now more concise and consistent. maybe you like the introduced changes in neural network.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will work with alt-thesis class, but give it a shot.

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{positioning}

 \newsavebox{\tempbox}

 \begin{document}

\tikzset{%
neuron missing/.style={
draw=none, 
scale=4,
text height=0.333cm,
execute at begin node=\color{black}$\vdots$
},
}

\savebox{\tempbox}{\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.5cm, y=1.5cm, >=stealth]

\foreach \m/\l [count=\y] in {1,2,3}
{
\node [circle,fill=green!50,minimum size=1cm] (input-\m) at (0,2.5-\y) {};
}
\foreach \m/\l [count=\y] in {4}
{
 \node [circle,fill=green!50,minimum size=1cm ] (input-\m) at (0,-2.5) {};
}

\node [neuron missing]  at (0,-1.5) {};


\foreach \m [count=\y] in {1}
\node [circle,fill=red!50,minimum size=1cm ] (hidden-\m) at (2,0.75) {};

\foreach \m [count=\y] in {2}
\node [circle,fill=red!50,minimum size=1cm ] (hidden-\m) at (2,-1.85) {};

\node [neuron missing]  at (2,-0.3) {};


\foreach \m [count=\y] in {1}
 \node [circle,fill=blue!50,minimum size=1cm ] (output-\m) at (4,1.5-\y) {};

\foreach \m [count=\y] in {2}
 \node [circle,fill=blue!50,minimum size=1cm ] (output-\m) at (4,-0.5-\y) {};

\node [neuron missing]  at (4,-0.4) {};

\foreach \l [count=\i] in {1,2,3,256}
 \draw [<-] (input-\i) -- ++(-1,0)
 node [above, midway] {$I_{\l}$};

\foreach \l [count=\i] in {1,16}
\node [above] at (hidden-\i.north) {$H_{\l}$};

\foreach \l [count=\i] in {1,16}
\draw [->] (output-\i) -- ++(1,0)
node [above, midway] {$O_{ \l}$};

\foreach \i in {1,...,4}
\foreach \j in {1,...,2}
\draw [->] (input-\i) -- (hidden-\j);

\foreach \i in {1,...,2}
\foreach \j in {1,...,2}
\draw [->] (hidden-\i) -- (output-\j);

 %\foreach \l [count=\x from 0] in {Input, Hidden, Ouput}
 % \node [align=center, above] at (\x*2,2) {\l \\ layer};

\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\usebox{\tempbox}
\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```